# Creating a dataset with Power BI's REST API and associate it with a custom connector

Tags: powerbi

I would like to know if it is currently possible to create a dataset in Power BI service, using the Power BI REST API, so that the dataset is associated with a data source whose type corresponds to a certified custom connector in Power BI.

In my scenario I have a Power BI custom connector that allows me to connect to and access data at a server in DirectQuery mode. I want to create a dataset in Power BI service through the Power BI REST API and connect it to a data source in my gateway. This data source has "Extension" as "datasourceType" because I use the custom connector.

Data source created with the Power BI REST API:

```
{
      "id": "7077dcea-6874-42ec-86df-40d3f4af7c50",
      "gatewayId": "52bbd773-b6c3-4b86-a6f0-e8a15551bc53",
      "datasourceType": "Extension",
      "connectionDetails": "{\"extensionDataSourceKind\":\"DenodoForPowerBI\",\"extensionDataSourcePath\":\"{\\\"DSN\\\":\\\"DenodoODBC\\\"}\"}",
      "credentialType": "Basic",
      "credentialDetails": {
        "useEndUserOAuth2Credentials": false
      },
      "datasourceName": "Testing_REST_API_02"
    }
```

Now I want to create a dataset bound to this data source. According to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdataset), it seems that the body of the request should be something like this:

```
{
        "name": "datasettest",
        "tables": [],
        "datasources": [
            {
                "datasourceType": "Extension",
                "gatewayId": "52bbd773-b6c3-4b86-a6f0-e8a15551bc53",
                "datasourceId": "7077dcea-6874-42ec-86df-40d3f4af7c50"
            }
        ]
}
```

This POST requests throws an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidRequest",
        "message": "TOM deserialization failed for database sobe_wowvirtualserver|c7da28ca-2b93-438e-9341-ddd9ceba4c61, Exception: <pi>Unrecognized JSON property: datasources. Check path 'datasources', line 1, position 67.</pi>"
    }
}
```

I do not know if this type of connector needs any specification that I am not taking into account or if this functionality is not supported.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Could you please share the command you use to create data source via REST API? I always get 400 on every try to do it.

Comment: I have created the data source with a POST request:

POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/{gatewayId}/datasources

Using the body of the request you should specify connection details, credential details, data source name and data source type. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/create-datasource for more information.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this doc. Seems that I have a problem with the encryption of credentials. Could you please share the way you used to encrypt it?

Comment: I do not remember very well the process used to encrypt the credentials. However, maybe you could use the developer tools of your browser and get the credentials during the authentication from powerbi.com.